# JPanel in a JFrame not listening to keys even when focused

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I have a JFrame called gameFrame and I added a Jpanel called introPanel to it, `gameFrame.add(introPanel)` and I wanted to listen to the JPanel with a keylistener so I added one. When the user presses Enter, I removed the JPanel from the gameFrame and added the MainMenu theoretically, however the program doesnt listen to my keys. So i looked online and through SO and found out that I had to make the panel focusable so I did:

```
public IntroMenuStart() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

However this did not work either. What else can I do to fix this?

Each Panel is a seperate class and they all get removed from gameframe and the next panel is added.

I would prefer to do this with keylistener.

**EDIT**

I fixed it by including this in my code for anyone wanting to know but I'm going to be changing my code to Keybindings like the 2 answers suggsted.

```
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to listne to the panel with a key listener so i add one. When
>   the user presses Enter, i remove to JPanel form the gameFrame and add
>   MainMenu, theoretically, however the program doesnt listen to my keys

If you search in deep in SO , you'll see that you have to use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
KeyListener has 2 greate issues, you listen to all keys and you have to have focus.
Instead KeyBinding you bind for a key and you don't have to be in focus.

Simple Example:

```
AbstractAction escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //code here example
         ((JComponent)e.getSource()).setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
    }};
 String key = "ESCAPE";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, key);
 component.getActionMap().put(key, escapeAction);
```

You can use these JComponent constants

```
    WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT 
    WHEN_FOCUSED 
    WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `JPanel` is not focuseable. Instead, use the key bindings.

- See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).